# What are the differences between Force.com and Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce Development. I am exploring the salesforce stack. What makes it difficult to me is differentiate force.com and Salesforce DX. Both have CLI and other facilities. What are the actual differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

Force.com is another word for the Salesforce Platform. Force.com development refers to developing on the Salesforce Platform. Things like custom objects, apex, visualforce, ligntning, workflows, packaging, etc are all part of the Salesforce Platform.

Historically, Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) has been very difficult with the Salesforce Platform because it can only run in the cloud. For example, how do you spin up an environment for your Continous Integration (CI) and Continuous Delivery (CD)?

Salesforce DX (Developer Experience) is a set or new tools and features to improve, well..., the developer experience and ALM of the Salesforce Platform. In other words, all of these new tools and features work against or are apart of the Salesforce Platform. A few of these new tools and features include:

- Scratch Orgs (making environments for development, CI, and CD easier)
- Developer Controlled Packages
- VSCode Extension
- The Salesforce CLI

You can read more information here: https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx

There are also a lot of trailheads now explaining the tool and feature set of Salesforce DX: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/sfdx_get_started

**Note:** The Force.com CLI will be deprecated in favor of the Salesforce CLI.